# Kotlin synthetic view in activity gets null when a custom dialog is shown and dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am updating a view in activity's onCreate method which is working fine using kotlin extension as stated below.

> Activity's **onCreate**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_otpverification.*

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_otpverification)
            tvContactNumber.text = getString(R.string.dual_string_value_placeholder)
        }
```

Then at a click of a **button** I am showing a **custom dialog** for performing some action. When the dialog is **dismissed** I update the same **textView** in activity with the data sent from dialog, but the view **tvContact** is throwing null exception.

> Activity's **onClick**

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    when (p0?.id) {
        R.id.ivEdit -> {
            object : ChangeNumberDialog(this) {
                override fun onSubmitClicked(number: String) {
                    tvContactNumber.text =number
                }
            }.show()
        }
    }
}
```

**onSubmitClicked** is an abstract method in the dialog which is triggered when the dialog is dismissed.

> Error from logcat :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: tvContactNumber must not be null
            at com.beat.em.ui.activities.OTPVerificationActivity$onClick$1.onSubmitClicked
(OTPVerificationActivity.kt:211)
```

> **onCreate** and **onClick** methods from the ***ChangeNumberDialog***:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_change_number, null, false)
        setContentView(view)
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        setCancelable(true)
        tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

  override fun onClick(view: View) {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.tvSubmit -> {
            onSubmitClicked(etNumber.text.toString().trim())
            dismiss()
          }
       }
  }
```

I have just started using kotlin extension and not able to understand the cause. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you are trying to access is in another scope, try to add explicit scope to the view i.e.

```
this@YourActivity.tvContactNumber.text = number
```